# Sending and receiving data over a network to a non-Ros computer

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if it is possible to send data over a network to another computer using TCP. One computer is running ROS and the other is not.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136001/sending-and-receiving-data-over-a-network-to-a-non-ros-computer./) by [iceburg6628](https://answers.ros.org/users/8586/iceburg6628/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is possible. You just have to use your custom TCP communication code inside a ROS node. You can then, for example receive data on a ROS topic via a callback, process it, and send it out to the non-ROS computer using your custom TCP connection setup.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iceburg6628](https://answers.ros.org/users/8586/iceburg6628/) on 2014-03-05**:
Thank you, I wasn't sure if their was a built in package.

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-03-06**:
How should I edit the CMakelists.txt if my program includes other libs and other .h files?Thank you ...

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-04-21**:
I have the same question.
Did you solve it?
Thanks a lot.